# WPF - Keep menu item enabled even when command's canExecute returns false

Tags: wpf, contextmenu, menuitem, canexecute

By default menu items are disabled when it's command's canExecute returns false. Is it possible to override this behavior? I need to keep menu item enabled even if canExecute is returning false without touching canExecute. Setting isEnabled to true for menu item did not work.

Comment: You'd introduce 'code smell' by doing so. That really sounds as a bad way to go.

Comment: Would it be good to remove command from menu item and invoke it separately on click?